# How should I store a static key pairs list?

Tags: 7

I wish to store around 200 static key value pairs.

A few ways i can think of, are the following:

```
 - Using `variable_set()` 
 - Using a custom table
 - Using a cache 
 - Defining a constant in code
 - hard-coding the key pairs
```

The list will be referenced on every node. I am using the Views module as well.

How should I store the key pairs list in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Regarding Using variable_get and variable_set

I would suggest storing them in variables tables using variable_set in serailized format.. Store your 200 pairs data in an array using variable_get function...

Variables are cached in cache_bootstrap table so that performance will be improved.

- Regarding Custom Table

You will lose the cache ability and managing the rows like edit/insert will be a pain since you need to build logic to retrieve and update results.

- Regarding Cache Table

It will be a temporary storage. If some one clears all cache you will lose the data.

- Regarding Constant in Code

Yes.. You can use constants too..  I am not sure performance impact vs using variables.

- Regarding Hardcoded in code

I believe it's same as using constants. But, If you are trying to hardcode everywhere then you will end up with redundant code which will result in update - data consistency problem.

If you think in Drupal way i will say variables is the way to go using variable_get and variable_set..

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how much return on invest this has. A few questions I'd throw out to myself if I were in your shoes:

- How often will this data change?
- Will I have to query individual parts of this data?
- How large is the contents for each key?

For the most part, if it's something simple, 200 keys isn't that many if the contents isn't huge. If you don't need to query the data, I'd just use the variable_get approach and maybe a getter function that used a static variable for request context caching. If you need to to query the data, apply permissions, include it in the display, or index in search then I'd say make a custom entity and have the key and value as properties.